# If Employee exists then return employee roles using ADO.net

Tags: c#, .net-core, ado.net

The idea under REST is, if an http request may come for an unknown record, we return 404, if it exists then roles of the employee.

The naive way would be that I can do this in two SQL statements, check the result of the first return null if not found else proceed with retrieving roles. The caller can check if result of the function is null and can return 404 based on that otherwise it will dislay roles of the user.

```
"SELECT Id FROM Employee WHERE Id = @Id"
"SELECT * FROM Role WHERE EmployeeId = @Id"
```

My current implementation is:

```
public List<object> GetUserRolesById(int id)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        // statement 1
        string sql = "SELECT Id FROM Employee WHERE Id = @Id";
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 32).Value = id;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (!reader.Read() || reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Id")))
                {
                    return null; // caller to return 404 if record not found
                }
            }
        }

        // statement 2
        sql = @"SELECT Id, Name FROM Role WHERE EmployeeId = @Id";
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 32).Value = id;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                List<object> roles = new List<object>();
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < roleIds.Length; i++)
                    {
                        roles.Add(new {Id = Int32.Parse(reader.GetString((0)), Name = reader.GetString(1)});
                    }
                }
                return roles;
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Question:

How can I combine both SQL statements in one in a nicer way?

**Edit**

Following the answer, incorporating suggestions in my solution, minus the user non-existent condition.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    string sql = @"
        SELECT Employee.Id, Role.Id AS [RoleId], Role.NAME AS [RoleName]
        FROM Employee
        LEFT OUTER JOIN EmployeeRole on Employee.Id = EmployeeRole.EmployeeId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Role on EmployeeRole.RoleId = Role.Id
        WHERE Employee.Id = @Id";

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            List<object> roles = new List<object>();
            while (reader.Read()) // 404 condition missing?
            {
                roles.Add(new {Id = reader.GetInt32(1), Name = reader.GetString(2)});
            }
            return roles;
        }
    }
}
```

**Query 2**

Will it work if we combine both queries? however, I don't know how to retrieve double query result from the reader.

```
string sql = @"SELECT FIRST FROM Employee WHERE Id = @Id;
    SELECT Employee.Id, Employee.First, Role.Id AS [RoleId], Role.NAME AS [RoleName]
    FROM Employee
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EmployeeRole on Employee.Id = EmployeeRole.EmployeeId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Role on EmployeeRole.RoleId = Role.Id
    WHERE Employee.Id = @Id2";
```

Comment: You may wish to consider using Dapper, rather than ADO.NET directly.

Comment: it's the requirement that Ive to use ado without any dependency or library/framework

Comment: just do this in the second statement `@"SELECT Id, Name FROM Role WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Id = @Id)";`, or better yet, use store procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using SQL like:

```
SELECT Employee.Id, Role.WhateverColumnYouWantHere
FROM Employee LEFT OUTER JOIN Role On Employee.Id = Role.EmployeeID
WHERE Employee.Id = @Id
```

If the employee isn't there then `Read` will return `false`. If the employee is there, but lacks a role, then `Role.WhateverColumnYouWantHere` will be `NULL` (`IsDBNull` will return `true`).

*Additionally, you likely want to remove your `for (int i = 0; i < roleIds.Length; i++)` loop (leave the logic inside it - just remove the loop) since it isn't doing anything useful. Also, change `if (reader.Read())` to `while (reader.Read())` to handle the possibility of multiple roles. Plus, you likely should use `reader.GetInt32(0)` rather than `Int32.Parse(reader.GetString((0))` - assuming that the `Id` is a 32-bit integer (rather than a string). Also, remove the `, 32` code - it is unnecessary, since `SqlDbType.Int` has a fixed size (i.e. it knows it is 32-bits).*

Comment: Inside the `while` you need to call `reader.IsDBNull(1)` (as per my answer). If it returns `true` then there **is** an employee, but they don't have a role.

Comment: @AppDeveloper Declare a boolean before the `while` loop. Call it `doesTheEmployeeExist` with a default value of `false`. Set it to `true` **inside** the `while` loop. Now you can distinguish whether the employee exists or not (as per my answer - based on the result of `Read`) based on the value of `doesTheEmployeeExist`)